# What args would I pass an event to be called from another event in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I hope I am understanding this correctly, I have an standard event for a datagrid (handles datagrid.CellClick) in the same form, I want to be able to call this or raise this event per se from another event, (one that handles the DataBindingComplete in the same datagrid)

If I am describing the problem in a weird way it's possibly due to fundamental lack of understanding this bit. I essentially just want to execute a cell click command after my datagrid is loaded, the way I thought of doing this is when it finishes loading (DataBinding) just click the first cell. I am unfortunately writing this in VB but C# answer works just as well to convey the message if you like.

I have tried just called the datagrid.CellClick as a function but of couse that doesn't work

```vb
Private Sub dgvItems_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvItems.CellClick
    If dgvItems.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
        If IsNothing(dgvItems.CurrentRow) Then Return

        dgvItems.CurrentRow.Selected = True
    End If

    SelectedItem = _Items.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = dgvItems.SelectedRows(0).Cells("name").Value.ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub dgvItems_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles dgvItems.DataBindingComplete
    dgvItems_CellClick()
End Sub
```

I would expect that the Items cell click would be called in the DataBindingComplete event and it would work as expected

Comment: Just move that code into another Sub so you can call it both ways.

Comment: Never call an event handler directly.  Just as you would in any other case, if you have code that needs to be executed from multiple places, you put that code in it's own method and then call that method from multiple places.